# cmocka.h: No such file or directory though cmocka installed -- IBM watson embedded C Client Library

Tags: c, embedded, ibm-watson, cmocka

I'm trying to compile Embedded C Client Library example for IBM watson.

I'm referring to **https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-embeddedc** for instructions.

While compiling I'm getting error as `cmocka.h` not found. I copied `cmocka.h` file manually to `/home/amruta/iot-embeddedc/test` but still getting same error.

**Path of cmocka.h :**

`/home/amruta/cmocka-1.1.0/include/cmocka.h`

**path of test_gatewayclient.c :**

```
/home/amruta/iot-embeddedc/test/test_gatewayclient.c
```

**Build path :**

`/home/amruta/iot-embeddedc/build`

**Error :**

```
[ 81%] Building C object test/CMakeFiles/test_gatewayclient.dir/test_gatewayclient.c.o
/home/amruta/iot-embeddedc/test/test_gatewayclient.c:5:20: fatal error: cmocka.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
test/CMakeFiles/test_gatewayclient.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'test/CMakeFiles/test_gatewayclient.dir/test_gatewayclient.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/test_gatewayclient.dir/test_gatewayclient.c.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:96: recipe for target 'test/CMakeFiles/test_gatewayclient.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/test_gatewayclient.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: This sounds like an IDE problem more than anything else. Which IDE and tool chain are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any IDE. Working on Ubuntu 16.04 terminal.

Comment: That's the root of your problem then... why debug your source code when you could be debugging make files? So post your make file.

Comment: https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-embeddedc - I'm refering this samples.

Comment: Please post the relevant part here, on this site.

Comment: File is too big to post. Is there any option available to attach file?

Comment: `/home/amruta/cmocka-1.1.0/include/cmocka.h` that's a strange path. Did you follow the steps and installed cmocka on your system? `a. curl -O https://git.cryptomilk.org/projects/cmocka.git/snapshot/cmocka-1.1.0.zip
b. unzip cmocka-1.1.0.zip
c. rm -f cmocka-1.1.0.zip
d. cd /home/cmocka-1.1.0/
e. mkdir build
f. cd /home/cmocka-1.1.0/build`

Comment: I have used following set of commands :                                                       Following was successful
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~$ cd cmocka-1.1.0/
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~/cmocka-1.1.0$ pwd
/home/amruta/cmocka-1.1.0
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~/cmocka-1.1.0$ mkdir build
----------------------Unsuccessful-------------------------
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~/cmocka-1.1.0$ cd /home/cmocka-1.1.0/build
bash: cd: /home/cmocka-1.1.0/build: No such file or directory

Comment: Following was successful
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~/cmocka-1.1.0$ cd /home/amruta/cmocka-1.1.0/build
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~/cmocka-1.1.0/build$ git clone https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-embeddedc.git
Cloning into 'iot-embeddedc'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 463, done.
remote: Total 463 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 463
Receiving objects: 100% (463/463), 216.19 KiB | 88.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (282/282), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~/cmocka-1.1.0/build$

Comment: amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~/cmocka-1.1.0/build$ export IOT_EMBDC_HOME=$HOME/iot-embeddedc/
--------------------Unsuccessful------------------------------
amruta@amruta-OptiPlex-3060:~/cmocka-1.1.0/build$ cd $IOT_EMBDC_HOME ; ./setup.sh
bash: cd: /home/amruta/iot-embeddedc/: No such file or directory
bash: ./setup.sh: No such file or directory